# Wildfly/Infinispan module property

Tags: wildfly-8, infinispan

We are using Wildfly Infinispan subsystem and we are quite confused about the purpose of **module** property in the definition of container. I mean the following:

```
<cache-container name="redirectCache" default-cache="default" module="deployment.OurPackage-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear">
    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
    <distributed-cache name="default" batching="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/infinispan/redirectCache" mode="ASYNC" owners="2" l1-lifespan="0"/>
</cache-container>
```

In Wildfly docs, there is: Defines the module whose class loader should be used when building this cache container.
What does it exactly mean? So far it seems we are able to access the cache just from the application package that is referred in this property. If there is a different module or no module at all, then the application does not seem to start.
Is it possible to share the cache across various applications? What should be in the module property then?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the module property only accepts valid jboss modules (defined in the extensions tag at the top of the standalone.xml file you are using). An example of this is the ['web' cache container](https://github.com/goldmann/wildfly-docker-configuration/blob/master/custom-file/standalone-custom.xml#L173) that uses the `org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan` module defined in the extensions.